# bootstrap by group in tibble

Tags: r, dplyr, broom

Suppose I have a tibble `tbl_`

```
tbl_ <- tibble(id = c(1,1,2,2,3,3), dta = 1:6)
tbl_
# A tibble: 6 x 2
     id   dta
  <dbl> <int>
1     1     1
2     1     2
3     2     3
4     2     4
5     3     5
6     3     6
```

There are 3 id groups. I want to resample entire id groups 3 times with replacement. For example the resulting tibble can be:

```
     id   dta
  <dbl> <int>
1     1     1
2     1     2
3     1     1
4     1     2
5     3     5
6     3     6
```

but **not**

```
     id   dta
  <dbl> <int>
1     1     1
2     1     2
3     1     1
4     2     4
5     3     5
6     3     6
```

or

```
     id   dta
  <dbl> <int>
1     1     1
2     1     1
3     2     3
4     2     4
5     3     5
6     3     6
```

Comment: Why `id = 1,1,2,2,3,3` case is not a valid option?

Comment: Because second row is 1 1, when it has to be 1 2.

Comment: That's correct. Make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one option with `sample_n` and `distinct`

```
library(tidyverse)
distinct(tbl_, id) %>% 
    sample_n(nrow(.), replace = TRUE) %>% 
    pull(id) %>% 
    map_df( ~ tbl_ %>% 
         filter(id == .x)) %>%
    arrange(id)
# A tibble: 6 x 2
#     id   dta
#  <dbl> <int>
#1  1.00     1
#2  1.00     2
#3  1.00     1
#4  1.00     2
#5  3.00     5
#6  3.00     6
```

Answer (score 0):

An option can be to get the `minimum` row number for each `id`.  That row number will be used to generate random samples from wiht `replace = TRUE`.

```
library(dplyr)

tbl_ %>% mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(minrow = min(rn)) ->min_row

indx <- rep(sample(min_row$minrow, nrow(min_row), replace = TRUE), each = 2) + 
        rep(c(0,1), 3)

tbl_[indx,]
# # A tibble: 6 x 2
#    id     dta
#   <dbl>  <int>
# 1  1.00     1
# 2  1.00     2
# 3  3.00     5
# 4  3.00     6
# 5  2.00     3
# 6  2.00     4
```

**Note:** In the above answer the number of rows for each `id` has been assumed as 2 but this answer can tackle any number of IDs. The hard-coded `each=2` and `c(0,1)` needs to be modified in order to scale it up to handle more than 2 rows for each `id`